# Linear regression - an increase in age effect the dependent variable?

Tags: regression, mathematical-modeling, linear-regression

The context:Part of an assignment for a linear regression course, examining the relationship between plasma retinal levels of patients and various lifestyle factors.

The question: What happens, on average, to the plasma retinal levels if we increase the age? Does the size of the change depend on the age?

My Answer: Given the linear model $\hat{Y}=\hat{\beta_{0}}+\hat{\beta_{1}}(X),$ (Y=plasma retinal levels, X=age), then in general, increasing the age by n years gives

$$\hat{\beta_{0}}+\hat{\beta_{1}}·(X+n)=\hat{\beta_{0}}+\hat{\beta_{1}}·(X)+n\hat{\beta_{1}}=\hat{Y}+n\hat{\beta_{1}}.$$
Implying that the size of the change of the Plasma Retinal levels on average is indeed dependent on the age of the patients.

The feedback: The answer to the question is not correct, i.e. the size of the change is not dependent on the age of the patient (ask yourself why it's not... Hint: your interpretation of the linear model is not correct)

The plea for help: I have being racking my head trying to see what exactly is wrong with my model but do not see the problem? Any help greatly appreciated.

*EDIT:*Since posting I realised that it may be argued that since $\frac{dy}{dx}=\beta_{1}$ then the change is not dependent on an increase in age? Is this correct? I would nonetheless still appreciate clarification for what is wrong with my original answer.

Comment: Were you supplied with data points? If yes, maybe you should have checked for correlation between plasma retinal levels and age. Were you given numerical values for the regression coefficients? Or at least were you told that $\beta_1$ is positive? If yes, then maybe your answer  could be correct, but the feedback says it's not the case. Also, even if you had computed $\beta_1$ from data, its value could have no statistical significance.

Comment: @RianKoja Yes we have data but we were told to solve this "by hand", not to use R. Both the $\beta_{0}$ and $\beta_{1}$ estimates are positive.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of your interpretation is not correct. Plasma retinal levels and age being positively correlated via a linear relationship is not the same as the amount of increase in retinal levels being dependent on age. That wouldn't be a linear relationship. That is, the slope of the graph doesn't change and your addition of n to the slope isn't correct.

Comment: There may be other aspects of this assignment to consider. Was there a study of a residual plot to see how well the data fit to a linear trend? And did it show a curved pattern?

Answer (score 0):

Case 1: The size of the change is independent of age:
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \epsilon_i,
$$ 
then 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathbb{E}[y|x] = \beta_1.
$$
I.e., the value of age $x$ does not effect the size of the change in the retina size.

Case 2: The size of the change is dependent on age:
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_i + \beta_2x_i^2 + \epsilon_i,
$$ 
then 
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathbb{E}[y|x= x_0] = \beta_1 + 2\beta_2x_0.
$$
I.e., the value of age $x$ effects the size of the change in the retina size and this effect depends on the magnitude and the sign of $\beta_2$.